# flutter - got stuck at splash screen

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I try to run my mobile apps that built using `flutter` but get stuck at a splash screen. Using `adb logcat` tools I can see some of error/exception but I have no idea which one of these exception cause the error:

```
codeinrain04-06 17:51:22.604  7234  7253 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
04-06 17:51:22.604  7234  7253 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app co.blocksite
04-06 17:51:22.619  7234  7234 W com.facebook.aa: Please set a value for AutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#disable-auto-events.
04-06 17:51:22.619  7234  7234 W com.facebook.aa: The value for AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled is currently set to FALSE so you're sending app events without collecting Advertiser ID. This can affect the quality of your advertising and analytics results.
04-06 17:51:22.656  7234  7259 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-06 17:51:22.803  7234  7234 I GAv4    : Google Analytics 12.4.51 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
04-06 17:51:22.803  7234  7234 I GAv4    :   adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
04-06 17:51:22.803  7234  7234 I GAv4    :   adb logcat -s GAv4
04-06 17:51:22.950   686   686 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:363678): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=14021 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-06 17:51:23.038  4040  7295 I CheckinUtil: Classify the device as Phone.
04-06 17:51:23.099  4040  7295 W Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
04-06 17:51:23.101  4040  7295 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@200914021@20.09.14 (040408-300565878):2)
04-06 17:51:23.101  4040  7295 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@200914021@20.09.14 (040408-300565878):0)
04-06 17:51:23.180  4040  7295 W Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
04-06 17:51:23.180  4040  7295 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@200914021@20.09.14 (040408-300565878):2)
04-06 17:51:23.180  4040  7295 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@200914021@20.09.14 (040408-300565878):0)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub is not available, please add com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub to the project.
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/co.blocksite-2VTx-MhglDslsD5oY8oe7g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.blocksite-2VTx-MhglDslsD5oY8oe7g==/split_config.in.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.blocksite-2VTx-MhglDslsD5oY8oe7g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/co.blocksite-2VTx-MhglDslsD5oY8oe7g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.facebook.a.b.g.a(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:611)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.facebook.a.b.g.a(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:633)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.facebook.a.b.g.a(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:627)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.facebook.a.b.g.a(InAppPurchaseEventManager.java:125)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.facebook.a.b.f$1.onServiceConnected(InAppPurchaseActivityLifecycleTracker.java:108)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1634)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1663)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/co.blocksite-2VTx-MhglDslsD5oY8oe7g==/split_config.in.apk
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2249)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5703)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        ... 5 more
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/co.blocksite-2VTx-MhglDslsD5oY8oe7g==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2249)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5703)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
04-06 17:51:23.299  7234  7234 E com.facebook.a.b.g:        ... 5 more
04-06 17:51:23.405  5872  5875 E nightwatch-watcher: Failed to read from logcat: Success
04-06 17:51:24.405  5872  5875 E nightwatch-watcher: Failed to read from logcat: Success
04-06 17:51:24.613  2485 27804 I AudioPolicyManagerCustom: FLAG None hence request for a primary output
04-06 17:51:24.613  2485 27804 I AudioPolicyManagerCustom: FLAG None hence request for a primary output
04-06 17:51:24.618   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xe69b1000)usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
04-06 17:51:24.619   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices for use case (low-latency-playback)
04-06 17:51:24.619   702   772 E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
04-06 17:51:24.620   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices: btsco_unavailable(0), mode(0), out_snd_device(speaker), in_snd_device(), BTSCO on?(0)
04-06 17:51:24.620   675 25117 D audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_get_anc_enabled: anc_enabled:0
04-06 17:51:24.620   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(84: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
04-06 17:51:24.620   675 25117 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(84) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg: new_snd_devices[0] is 84
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_get_anc_enabled: anc_enabled:0
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: playback on codec device not supporting native playback set default Sample Rate(48k)
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: Codec selected backend: 0 updated bit width: 16 and sample rate: 48000
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: force routing 0
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 E msm8974_platform: platform_check_backends_match: Invalid snd_device = 
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: (59) check_usecases curr device: speaker, usecase device: backends match 0
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: check_usecases num.of Usecases to switch 0
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D audio_hw_spkr_prot: set_spkr_prot_cal: quick calibration disabled
04-06 17:51:24.621   675 25117 D audio_hw_spkr_prot: audio_extn_spkr_prot_start_processing: snd_device(84: speaker)
04-06 17:51:24.637   675 25117 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = vi-feedback
04-06 17:51:24.637   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(242) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
04-06 17:51:24.637   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(242: vi-feedback)
04-06 17:51:24.637   675 25117 D audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg: usecase->in_snd_device vi-feedback
04-06 17:51:24.637   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(242) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
04-06 17:51:24.638   675 25117 E audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device: Could not get ctl for mixer cmd - Audio Stream Capture 42 App Type Cfg
04-06 17:51:24.638   675 25117 E voice   : voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
04-06 17:51:24.638   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(242) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
04-06 17:51:24.638   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 102, path = 1, app id = 0x11132, sample rate = 48000
04-06 17:51:24.638   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
04-06 17:51:24.638   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
04-06 17:51:24.639   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
04-06 17:51:24.639   675 25117 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply mixer and update path: spkr-vi-record
04-06 17:51:24.696   675 25117 E voice   : voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
04-06 17:51:24.696   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(249) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
04-06 17:51:24.696   675 25117 D msm8974_platform: Resetting app type for Tx path to default
04-06 17:51:24.696   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 4, path = 1, app id = 0x11132, sample rate = 8000
04-06 17:51:24.696   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
04-06 17:51:28.902   693   693 I WifiHAL : Got channel list with 0 channels
04-06 17:51:34.180   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audstrmtable
04-06 17:51:34.180   675 25117 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TABLE_V2
04-06 17:51:34.536  6400  7364 I PlayCommon: [4374] amjg.c(160): Connecting to server: https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
04-06 17:51:34.546  7337  7355 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
04-06 17:51:34.546  7337  7355 I DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
04-06 17:51:34.546  7337  7355 V DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
04-06 17:51:34.582  6400  7364 I PlayCommon: [4374] amjg.c(187): Successfully uploaded logs.
04-06 17:51:34.586  7337  7355 I DynamiteLoaderV2: [71] AdsFdrDynamite.integ
04-06 17:51:34.627  6400  7357 I Finsky  : [4372] kzb.a(3): Flushing event logs for [2PfsML0Opm97BNp3Vmjneg0WGYl9g1k4XoksxIgDcKo]
04-06 17:51:34.630  7337  7355 W zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
04-06 17:51:34.640  6400  7370 I PlayCommon: [4375] amjg.c(26): Preparing logs for uploading
04-06 17:51:34.652  2595  2595 D QSEECOMAPI: Loaded image: APP id = 15532035
04-06 17:51:34.653  6400  7370 I PlayCommon: [4375] amjg.c(160): Connecting to server: https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
04-06 17:51:34.656  6400  7226 I PlayCommon: [4370] amjg.c(187): Successfully uploaded logs.
04-06 17:51:34.674  7337  7337 I FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Instance ID e8A6chHg1Aw
04-06 17:51:34.680  4670  7353 I FSA2_SyncState: @readSyncState: # anav@1cf57a1d
04-06 17:51:34.682  7337  7366 I FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
04-06 17:51:34.683  7337  7366 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-06 17:51:34.683  7337  7366 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
04-06 17:51:34.683  7337  7366 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app z.zapps
04-06 17:51:34.695  7337  7376 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-06 17:51:34.705  6400  7370 I PlayCommon: [4375] amjg.c(187): Successfully uploaded logs.
04-06 17:51:34.736  2595  2595 D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_dealloc_memory 
04-06 17:51:34.736  2595  2595 D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_shutdown_app, app_id = 15532035
04-06 17:51:34.742  7337  7337 D NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: false
04-06 17:51:34.749  6400  7357 I Finsky  : [4372] kzb.a(3): Flushing event logs for [C2HVsP0RayqcvyZDLh2MyqiGl_QkpHbeZvmi7nFXm6I]
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool: NetClient: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x00 at 15 in header value: 358970073360390??
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue(Headers.java:295)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder.set(Headers.java:275)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder.header(Request.java:185)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.sonymobile.deviceconfigtool.utils.NetClient.executeHttpRequestImpl(NetClient.java:209)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.sonymobile.deviceconfigtool.utils.NetClient.executeHttpRequest(NetClient.java:91)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.sonymobile.deviceconfigtool.utils.NetClient.executeHttpRequest(NetClient.java:79)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.sonymobile.deviceconfigtool.cloudconfig.CloudConfigurator.handleImeiCheck(CloudConfigurator.java:600)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.sonymobile.deviceconfigtool.cloudconfig.CloudConfigurator.handleCloudIntent(CloudConfigurator.java:196)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at com.sonymobile.deviceconfigtool.EnterpriseConfigService$IntentHandler.run(EnterpriseConfigService.java:131)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
04-06 17:51:34.761  6146  6600 E DeviceConfigTool:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
04-06 17:51:34.766  7337  7379 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-06 17:51:34.778  7337  7337 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
04-06 17:51:35.041  6400  7357 I Finsky  : [4372] urh.a(16): SCH: jobFinished: 16-16161616. TimeElapsed: 656ms.
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : 8aaecb6, Ib515ec08c2
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 10/19/17
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.20.00.04
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : 
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.6.5.R1.08.00.00.312.030
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : NONE
04-06 17:51:35.225  7337  7337 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
04-06 17:51:35.227  7337  7337 I vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
04-06 17:51:35.233  7337  7337 I Adreno  : PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
04-06 17:51:35.353  2707  2717 I zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 206277(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 90(13MB) LOS objects, 34% free, 46MB/70MB, paused 8.313ms total 488.411ms
04-06 17:51:35.411  5872  5875 E nightwatch-watcher: Failed to read from logcat: Success
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'defaultBinaryMessenger' was called on null.
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : Receiver: null
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : Tried calling: defaultBinaryMessenger
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #0      defaultBinaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:90)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #1      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:349)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #4      MethodChannelSharedPreferencesStore.getAll (package:shared_preferences_platform_interface/method_channel_shared_preferences.dart:54)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #5      SharedPreferences._getSharedPreferencesMap (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:166)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #6      SharedPreferences.getInstance (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:33)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #7      _prefs (package:zapps/src/translations.dart:11)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #8      _prefs (package:zapps/src/translations.dart:11)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #9      Translations._getApplicationSavedInformation (package:zapps/src/translations.dart:109)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #10     Translations.getPreferredLanguage (package:zapps/src/translations.dart:57)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #11     Translations.setNewLanguage (package:zapps/src/translations.dart:69)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #12     Translations.init (package:zapps/src/translations.dart:48)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #13     main (package:zapps/main.dart:20)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #14     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:239)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #17     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #18     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #19     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #20     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : #21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174)
04-06 17:51:35.661  7337  7423 E flutter : 
04-06 17:51:35.790  7337  7337 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
04-06 17:51:35.790  7337  7337 I DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
04-06 17:51:35.793  7337  7337 D DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
04-06 17:51:35.793  7337  7337 D DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.ChimeraRewardedVideoAdCreatorImpl
04-06 17:51:35.816  7337  7337 I Ads     : Updating ad debug logging enablement.
04-06 17:51:35.851  7337  7337 I FIAM.Headless: Setting display event listener
04-06 17:51:35.854  7337  7337 I FIAM.Headless: went foreground
04-06 17:51:35.861  7337  7375 I FIAM.Headless: Forcing fetch from service rather than cache. Test Device: false | App Fresh Install: true
04-06 17:51:35.863  7337  7375 W FIAM.Headless: Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/z.zapps/files/fiam_impressions_store_file (No such file or directory)
04-06 17:51:35.866  7337  7375 I FIAM.Headless: Fetching campaigns from service.
04-06 17:51:36.078  2707  2869 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{5d68e67 u0 z.zapps/.MainActivity t1343} time:138503622 diff:1987 start:cold| batt:56|2 mw:off|1 mem:759588|0|68|13|14 cpu:[1593600, 1593600, 1824000, 1824000]
04-06 17:51:36.081  7337  7337 I TAG     : All location settings are satisfied.
04-06 17:51:36.087  2707  2784 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityStopTrigger 
04-06 17:51:36.093   702   772 E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/clk_scaling/enable with 0
04-06 17:51:36.093   702   772 E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER:  return value 2
04-06 17:51:37.474   675  1389 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby: exit
04-06 17:51:37.722  3817  3889 I QCNEJ/CndHalConnector: -> SND notifyWifiStatusChanged(RatInfo{type=1, subType=101, state=CONNECTED, v4=IfaceAddrPair{iface=wlan0, addr=192.168.1.4}, v6=IfaceAddrPair{iface=, addr=}, timestamp=2020-04-06 17:51:37.721, isAndroidValidated=true, netHandle=566952119006, slotIdx=0} WifiInfo{freq=TWO_GHz, state=3, ssid=fh_5e7090, bssid=00:67:62:5e:70:90, dns=[192.168.1.1, 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, ]})
04-06 17:51:38.090   686   686 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:363701): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=14021 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-06 17:51:38.200   686   686 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) memtrack@1.0-se identical 4 lines
04-06 17:51:38.200   686   686 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:363706): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=14021 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-06 17:51:38.414  5872  5875 E nightwatch-watcher: Failed to read from logcat: Success
```

Note: I'm building using CodeMagic.io with Stable Channel Version.

any idea?

Comment: I think this will help

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47033

Comment: What the flutter doctor -v says? In what version of flutter this project was created?

Comment: @ChrisPapantonis i'm building using CodeMagic.IO with flutter stable version, so i think no need to include flutter doctor...

Comment: Is `Translations.init` called before `runApp` in your `main` file?

Comment: @Ovidiu Hi, yes... is it the problem ?

Comment: @Ovidiu However, i see history of code, it has been there for long time, but no error so far at that time...

Comment: The way the Flutter binding (to the native side) has recently changed, and yes, that is most likely the problem

Comment: Is local build working? Add you `app` and `main` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is caused by invoking platform channels **before** calling `runApp`.

Since the last stable Flutter version, doing so requires you to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` beforehand, which ensures that Flutter is bound to the platform it's running on before you actually try to communicate to it using platform channels.

Calling this before any other code that makes use of platform channels should fix your issue - I guess you could have it as the very first line of code in your `main()` function:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

**Edit: My answer is only valid for the specific inner exception that the author was getting:**

```
E flutter : Tried calling: defaultBinaryMessenger
E flutter : #0      defaultBinaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:90)
E flutter : #1      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140)
E flutter : #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314)
```

It is possible you are getting the exact same outer exception, but with a completely different inner exception (root cause), in which case my answer does not apply!

Comment: Thanks Ovidiu but this solution does not work for me. I am still getting above error. Thanks again.